# is it safe to change the parent UUID of a received BTRFS snapshot

Tags: btrfs

imagine you're working with the same operating system root directory tree, but between versions some library versions or other files change. you take a snapshot of version 1 of that OS tree, make some changes, then send + compress the snapshot to another machine and want to decompress + mount it on a version 2 OS tree.

even though this can be done in an ugly manual way by changing the parent UUID of the received snapshot, and would surely work and be fine doing so for a version 1 tree... is it always safe to do on a version 2 tree? and if not, in what situations and why not?